# Create a checkbox list from a List<SelectListItem> collection

Tags: checkboxlist, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I worked on a project where I needed to create a checkbox list from a series of model values, and then retrieve the values from the controller on post. Unfortunately, unchecked checkboxes are simply not sent to the form collection on post, and testing each for null makes for clunky and ungainly code. But it turns out that adding hidden fields for the text and value of each SelectListItem makes grabbing the selected values on post a snap, so I built upon some code I found online for creating a checkbox list via a TagHelper. Works great, and I've included comments to show how the TagHelper is used in the view, how to register it, and how to collect the selected values in the controller. Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates a checkbox list that can be easily accessed in the model. 
/// <para>Example use in view: <checkboxlist asp-items="@Model.SomeSelectList" asp-model-name="SomeSelectList" asp-container="ul" asp-item="li"></checkboxlist></para>
/// <para>Example registration in _ViewImports file: @addTagHelper *, SomeNamespace</para>
/// <para>Example of retrieving selected values from model: model.SomeSelectList.Where(sl => sl.Selected == true).Select(sl => sl.Value).ToList()</para>
/// </summary>
[HtmlTargetElement("checkboxlist", Attributes = "asp-items, asp-model-name, asp-container, asp-item")]
public class CheckboxListTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-items")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-model-name")]
    public string ModelName { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-container")]
    public string Container { get; set; }

    private string _containerId;
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-container-id")]
    public string ContainerId 
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_containerId) ? $"id=\"{_containerId}\"" : ""; }
        set { _containerId = value; } 
    }

    private string _containerName;
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-container-name")]
    public string ContainerName 
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_containerName) ? $"name=\"{_containerName}\"" : ""; }
        set { _containerName = value; }
    }

    private string _containerClass;
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-container-class")]
    public string ContainerClass
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_containerClass) ? $"class=\"{_containerClass}\"" : ""; }
        set { _containerClass = value; }
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-item")]
    public string Item { get; set; }

    private string _itemId;
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-item-id")]
    public string ItemId
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_itemId) ? $"id=\"{_itemId}\"" : ""; }
        set { _itemId = value; }
    }

    private string _itemName;
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-item-name")]
    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_itemName) ? $"id=\"{_itemName}\"" : ""; }
        set { _itemName = value; }
    }

    private string _itemClass;
    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-item-class")]
    public string ItemClass
    {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_itemClass) ? $"id=\"{_itemClass}\"" : ""; }
        set { _itemClass = value; }
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append($@"<{Container} {ContainerId} {ContainerName} {ContainerClass}>");

        var index = 0;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            var selected = item.Selected ? @"checked=""checked""" : "";
            var disabled = item.Disabled ? @"disabled=""disabled""" : "";

            sb.Append($@"<{Item} {ItemId} {ItemName} {ItemClass}>");
            sb.Append($@"<input type=""checkbox"" {selected} {disabled} id=""{ModelName}_{index}__Selected"" name=""{ModelName}[{index}].Selected"" value=""true"" /> ");
            sb.Append($@"<label for=""{ModelName}_{index}__Selected"">{item.Text}</label>");
            sb.Append($@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{index}__Text"" name=""{ModelName}[{index}].Text"" value=""{item.Text}"">");
            sb.Append($@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{ModelName}_{index}__Value"" name=""{ModelName}[{index}].Value"" value=""{item.Value}"">");
            sb.Append($@"</{Item}>");

            index++;
        }

        sb.Append($@"</{Container}>");

        output.Content.AppendHtml(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

My new project uses the full .NET Framework, which for some reason doesn't support TagHelpers, so I created an extension method for the SelectListItem collection. This is a stripped-down version of the TagHelper class I posted above, since I didn't need all the bells and whistles. I'm using Bootstrap 3.4.1 for scaffolding on the page that uses this extension method, so I used a default container of a div with class "form-check". Here's the code for the extension method:

```
public static string GenerateCheckboxList(this List<SelectListItem> selectListItems, string modelName)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        var index = 0;
        foreach (var item in selectListItems)
        {
            var selected = item.Selected ? @"checked=""checked""" : "";
            var disabled = item.Disabled ? @"disabled=""disabled""" : "";

            sb.Append($@"<div class=""form-check"">");

            sb.Append($@"<label for=""{modelName}_{index}__Selected"">{item.Text}</label> ");
            sb.Append($@"<input type=""checkbox"" {selected} {disabled} id=""{modelName}_{index}__Selected"" name=""{modelName}[{index}].Selected"" value=""true"" class=""form-check-input"" />");
            sb.Append($@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{modelName}_{index}__Text"" name=""{modelName}[{index}].Text"" value=""{item.Text}"">");
            sb.Append($@"<input type=""hidden"" id=""{modelName}_{index}__Value"" name=""{modelName}[{index}].Value"" value=""{item.Value}"">");

            sb.Append($@"</div>");

            index++;
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I forgot to mention... when rendering the generated string in the view, you need to include a call to render the raw content, or the rendering engine will encode the HTML and it will look bizarre. This is all that's needed in the view:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.CheckboxList)
```